# Connectivity between standalone container and swarm service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-swarm

I created a standalone container for php based website that is suppose to get data from mysql database.
On same VM, i started swarm service for mysql.
I noticed following
1) When I publish ports in mysql service, it was by default connecting to ingress network (which is obvious) so no questions there
2) When I do not publish any port, it got connected to "bridge" network by default. Should it connect to docker_gwbridge network created by swarm? or may I am missing something

2nd point related to DNS resolution, I was able to create a user defined bridge network for my php website and also manually attached the mysql container (which was created inside swarm) directly to that user defined network (I know not a good practice, but was trying to play around). This way, I was able to use DNS resolution as they both being on same network, I just provided mysql container name and my website started working. But ofcourse this will not long live, as my containers can get change over the period of time.  
Hence My 2nd question is -  
Can I provide DNS name of my swarm service (rather container) in my php db connection string (created in stand alone container). I was not able to make it work as service belongs to different network it seems